# Sensor for detecting air leak

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi

I need to monitor if a CPAP mask is leaking air, and where such leak is.

[image: CPAP mask]

The monitoring will be the whole night receiving info from the sensor(s) and registering it into a raspberry pi.

Is there any sensor that can detect it?

Comment: From the close reasons:
*Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic.*

Comment: From my engineering point of view: wow, have you put any thought in how hard it is to detect a low pressure-difference, potentially underpressure leak in a gas of the same composition? Like, give me a room full of experienced engineers, 500 kg of the best coffee beans, budget on demand, and we'll have a proof of concept in less then a year. Less than a month, if flooding the room with a hydrogen fluoride/inert gas mixture of the same density as air and watching where the explosion starts with a disposable high-speed camera is an option.

Comment: Also, if this is about making non-ER-rated medical devices safe for use as ventilators: you're like, 9 months late to the show and [probably not the right kind of engineer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491579/creating-lung-ventilation-to-fight-covid-19/491591#491591).

Comment: Precisely what physical effect are you planning to sense? Pressure difference? Whistling noise? Temperature difference? .... ?

Comment: The CPAP mask **has to** leak air so that exhalation is possible. There are a series of valves around the house swivel. Most machines monitor and record pressure and can log the results.

Comment: Modern CPAP machines (e.g. ResMed AirSense 10) have a built-in function that monitors the integrity of the mask and will report any problems to the user. I doubt if you could provide an external sensing system that would be better than this considering reliability, ease of use, cost, need for another power source, etc.

Comment: Have a look at MEMS and replace the Raspberry Pi with a MCU (and perhaps a Arduino IDE compatible board)

Comment: As someone who uses a CPAP mask every night, I can tell you this:  1.  Air is constantly escaping through the exhaust vents.  It is usually quiet, except when condensation gets in the exhaust holes (it whistles and makes fizzing noises) or when a piece of cloth gets in the way (wind sounds.)  2. If not properly adjusted, it will leak air around the nose.  It blows in your eyes.  If the whistling doesn't wake you, you will have red eyes in the morning. 3. It can sporadically leak around the jaw line, usually accompanied by whistling or farting noises.

Comment: 4. It leaks around the hose where it plugs into the mask.  This makes a loud hissing noise. 5. It leaks through cracks in the soft gasket if you don't replace it (or the mask) on schedule.  The cracks will hiss, or make whistling noises, or fizzy noises (if condensation gets in the crack.)  6.  Condensation inside the mask **sucks.** It makes all air leaks noisier, and it makes the mask uncomfortable.  You need the humidifier, but it is difficult to get right.  Not enough humidity, and you sneeze blood from dried out mucus membranes.  Too much and the mask makes noise and your face is wet.

Comment: As others have mentioned, the machines log a **lot** of data on air pressure and leakage.  The logs won't tell you where a leak is but they may tell you if there's a leak.

Comment: If you really want to find leaks, try an [acoustic camera.](https://www.cae-systems.de/en/products/acoustic-camera-sound-source-localization/soundcam.html)  I don't know if the resolution is high enough, but it would be a start.  As a mask user, trust me - leaks make noise.

Comment: @JRE I didn't know that was a product you can buy, awesome!! That'd be among the first things my room of coffee-fueled engineers would have looked into (Schlierenphotography and UV-reflective dust being the others). Developing that for ultrasonic ranges (which I *hope* is a component in the whistling) would have nice secondary uses. Maybe a lower-cost solution would have been to glue microphones all over the mask and patient and just try to work on the recordings of these.

Comment: @MarcusMüller:  Es ist ausgerechnet eine Deutsche Firma die das Dingens herstellt.  I couldn't find a price list.  I suspect they fall into the "if you have to ask then you can't afford it" category.  They don't even tell you what it would cost to rent one, though they do offer to rent them out.

Comment: @JRE well, "National Instruments partners" kind of implies expensive digitizers ;) the rent business model is a clever one, but my guess is the real money is made when someone with e.g. a broken aircraft engine needs a signal processing expert to tell them how to interpret the results

Comment: @JRE other than that, broadband beamforming is an interesting topic with lots of interesting theory and optimal estimators for different meanings of "optimal"; I think I'd have had a lot of fun developing that product :)